# selecting one checkbox selects all of them in table vue

Tags: vue.js, pug

I have front end in jade where I have a table which contains checkboxes. I fetch user data from the database and I display user id and which user needs to be selected with checkboxes in table. Now the problem is selecting one checkbox selects all the checkboxes in the table. The v-model selectedUsers is an array declared in vue data.

```
            .table-responsive.mt-2
              table.table.table-striped.table-bordered
                thead
                  tr
                    th= u.t("field.include")
                    th= u.t("field.user_id")

                tbody
                  tr(v-for="user in users")
                    td
                      checkbox(
                        :id="user.userId",
                        :value="user",
                        v-model="selectedUsers"
                      )
                    td {{user.userId}}
```

Comment: This is not a valid Pug syntax `th= u.t("field.user_id")`

Comment: could you provide the script?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim there is no js script against it yet. According to my knowledge vue takes care of this automatically that whateevr user will be selected through checkbox it will add it in v-model selectedUsers array. But I cannot select a single checkbox. All cehckboxes get selected along with it. FOr this I shouldnt need any js script right now. Is it correct?

Comment: @QuentinVeron it is valid. It is just to display the text

Comment: try to add an unique id to each checkbox like `checkbox(
                        :value="user",:id="user.userId",
                        v-model="selectedUsers"
                      )`

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim I have tried this it still doesnt work. I will edit my question with this

Comment: could you share your work in https://codesandbox.io ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
tr(v-for="(user, i) in users")
    td
        checkbox(
            :id="user.userId",
            :value="user",
             v-model="selectedUsers[i]"
             )
```

So at least every checkbox will be liked to diffrent array item.
Note that currently the value looks static...